# Exposing optional arguments of a nested method in python

Tags: python, function, optional-parameters

A similar question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913256/python-optional-arguments-for-function-calling-lower-level-functions) but I don't know that I like the answer. You have a parent function, which calls a child function.

```
def parent(a):
   return child(a) * 2

def child(a, b=10, c=20):
   return a + b + c
```

If I want the parent method to expose `b` and `c`, I can do something like below. It works, but seems cumbersome, as I'm reaching for it a lot (maybe that suggests some other problem).

```
def parent(a, b=None, c=None):

    kwargs = {}
    if b is not None:
        kwargs['b']=b
    if c is not None:
        kwargs['c']=c

    return child(a, **kwargs)
```

Is there a better (i.e. less code) way to do this?

Comment: *Where* was it asked before? Place a bounty on that question asking for new answers.

Comment: Why don't you set the default values for b and c in parent() to the default values of b and c in child()? Then you can just call `child(a=a, b=b, c=c)`.

Comment: I may be mistaken but right now isn't parent identical to child? `parent = child` has the exact same functionality?

Comment: @9769953 child was defined earlier. the defaults for child make sense. what if other methods want to call child? I want them to also have access to those sensible defaults

Comment: seems that this isn't a duplicate after all. OP is aware of the solutions, and it looks not that good. Besides the question is more generic and understandable

Comment: @Primusa updated, though I think it's a bit besides the point ;)

Comment: Your comment doesn't contradict my suggestion: set the default values of parent to those used in child. You don't (need to) alter child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If parent and child are both your own functions, then you could have the default values defined as a constant that is shared for both functions.

```
B_DEF = 10
C_DEF = 20

def parent(a, b=B_DEF, c=C_DEF):
   return child(a,b,c) * 2

def child(a, b=B_DEF, c=C_DEF):
   return a + b + c
```